# missing modversions.h on linux

Tags: linux, module

I have configured and built linux kernel 2.6.27 successfully, with module supported enabled. But when I am trying to build another program (kernel module) that needs include/linux/modversions.h, it cannot find the file.

my question is: besides enabling the module support in linux kernel config,  is there anything else I need to do to generate/get the modversions.h?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run a `find /path/to/kernel -name modversions.h`, you'll probably find one in a `config` dir and another on a `linux` dir, if so it was compiled with your kernel.

If that module was compiled then it can be installed with `make modules_install`, though that will install all the compiled modules, not their headers.

To tell gcc to search for the kernel source when compiling use the -I option `-I/path/to/kernel`.
You can also use the INCLUDE_DIRS var to tell gcc to include that dir, `export INCLUDE_DIRS=$INCLUDE_DIRS:/path/to/kernel`.

Comment: Yes I can find one in "config" dir, but not in "linux" dir. And that's the problem because other module source code includes this header via "linux" dir.